# Why use extra parenthesis in booleens in CQL?

Tags: syntax, cql

According to [A Gentle Introduction to CQL](http://zing.z3950.org/cql/intro.html), one can add additional parenthesis to make the "query more clearly". Here is the example they list:

> (((((foo))) and (((((((((((((bar)))))))))))) or (baz))))

How does this make a query more clear? When would I want to add all of these extra parenthesis?

Comment: That isn't an example of a clear query. The paragraph before says *"For example, the following queries are all equivalent:"* which means it's an example of extra parenthesis not making a difference in parsing of the query.

Comment: I thought the meaning was, if you add these, it will be easier to read them somehow, but I cannot see how, so wondered why this would be used. I am assuming the fourth example line is the only one with redundant parenthesis. Are the other 3 before redundant also?

Comment: They are *all* redundant by definition if they're added only for clarity.